# How to Group fields, and duplicate them?

Tags: entities

I'm trying to create a type of buzz feed website where you can make a list of items.

If you set the body field setting to unlimited.
You get a "Add item" button.

You can duplicate the body field as many times as you want.

I want to duplicate a set of fields using the "Add item" button

title, image, description as one item.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also go for the [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) module. More details from its project page:

> This project seeks to provide a true compound field solution for Drupal 7. As much as I love Field collection, it still has to save actual entities, and can cause performance problems due to having to load all the referenced field collection entities on node, or parent entity load.

How to use [multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) check listed links :

- Video demo [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmSgmMIZMfw&feature=youtu.be)
- How [Creating multiple value field groups](http://openconcept.ca/blog/mducharme/creating-multiple-value-field-groups-drupal-7) .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using these modules:

[Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group)

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.
>
> The field group project is a follow-up on the field group module in
>   CCK. The release will only exist for Drupal 7 release and higher, so
>   since the existence of the Fields API in core. By moving field group
>   to a separate module, this may open some new perspectives.

[Field Group Multiple](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple)

> This module extends the Field group module by displays and widgets
>   which group multiple fields by there items.
>
> Grouping types:
>
> - Multiple fields container
> - Multiple fields table
> - Multiple fields as label-value